# Button doesn't work when assigned any drawable

Tags: android, eclipse

A strange thing happened which i never faced earlier, I am using a button which performs something through ontouchlistener, before assigning any drawable to the button it works fine but when i assign a drawable to it , it stops performing the function which it is supposed to.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Impossible,However I guess you are just expecting it to have an animation of being pressed when touched, [For that, see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529481/glow-when-touch-the-screen-in-android)

Comment: you are adding same `@drawable/image` for both `android:background` and `android:src`

Comment: post your class code here

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the background and src as same image.

This seems your error

Make button xml code :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image" />
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: As far as I know Buttons don't have `android:src`, they only have `background`. `ImageView` and `ImageButton` have `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

Change the Button to ImageView in activity xml.

Replace

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

With

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

And then in Activity Java

```
ImageView button1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your work here
         }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This error made no sense to me, it never happened to me ever before. But turns out that i solve my problem when i made an XML file in my drawable, and assigning my button to it. The xml file is as bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb"/>
</selector>
```

Strange but worked for me and i thought to share it with you all.

Thank-you for all the people who made their efforts to answer.